# Add multiple images to a page sidebar

Tags: custom-field, images, metabox, attachments, sidebar

What I am trying to achieve is this:

I have a simple page and I want to dynamically add multiple images to it on the sidebar one underneath another. I was thinking about either using meta boxes, post thumbnail or custom field. I am looking for a nice and simple method to do that.

Here is a screenshot that better explain what I am looking for:

http://bit.ly/y4Vi19

Notice that adding images to the post itself must be differ than add images to the sidebar.

any help will be appreciated

Thanks, Gil

Comment: Just found this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4trDns716U

this is really exactly what I want, even without the images order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using MetaBoxes.

A nice tutorial is here: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/

Comment: It looks like a very useful framework, however, I was looking for a solution which doesn't require a framework or plugin. I saw many tutorials online but none of them included image uploader in a Meta Box. I would love to get a snippet which does this magic.
I appreciate your generous help!

Answer (score 3):

I have no affiliation with this plugin, but I can vouch for how great and useful it is. The plugin is free and allows you to create custom meta boxes and fields for your post editing screens. However what you're asking for the ability to have a repeating field requires you pay $25 for the serial key to get the functionality. The plugin is called [Advanced Custom Fields](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/).

If you would prefer a complete free plugin that does the same thing and gives you the repeatable image field functionality out of the box, [Simple Fields](http://eskapism.se/code-playground/simple-fields/) is also a good plugin. I think the current site version isn't compatible with Wordpress 3.3, but it has a link to a version on Github that does.

Comment: Again, great help indeed. I thank you for that, however I am still looking for a good Meta Box snippet. I might consider using those plugins if I don't find a good code solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin: http://www.greatwpplugins.com/extra-category-content/. I add with it all kind of content to my categories. Maybe It will fit you too.